# Subtract ISO 8601 timestamps in Oracle

Tags: oracle, type-conversion, timestamp, unix-timestamp, iso8601

I want to subtract two timestamps in ISO 8601 format (2021-08-24T12:59:35Z - 2021-08-24T12:59:05Z)
Think the easiest way is convert this timestamp to epoch and then subtract.
Just can't get the syntax right for the conversion.
How do I convert 2021-08-24T12:59:05Z to this : 1629809975 ?

Comment: What answer - and data type - are you trying to get for those two starting values? And what data type are you starting from - strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the comment says, a lot depends on how you want the result formatted.

If you are ok with an `INTERVAL`, then the easiest thing to do is use `TO_UTC_TIMESTAMP_TZ` which actually takes an ISO 8601 formatted string as a parameter:

```sql
SELECT TO_UTC_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2021-08-24T12:59:35Z') - TO_UTC_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2021-08-24T12:59:05Z') AS RESULT
FROM DUAL;
```

Which returns this result:

| RESULT |
| --- |
| +000000000 00:00:30.000000000 |

Otherwise, if you want the number of seconds, you can incorporate `CAST` and `ROUND` to get the result:

```sql
SELECT ROUND((CAST(TO_UTC_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2021-08-24T12:59:35Z') AS DATE) - CAST(TO_UTC_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2021-08-24T12:59:05Z') AS DATE)) * 86400)  AS RESULT
FROM DUAL;
```

| RESULT |
| --- |
| 30 |

Here is a DBFiddle showing both options ([DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6597034da5fb26f65fb2cf8ebcfab7d7))

Comment: In case you don't run Oracle 10 yet, use `TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2021-08-24T12:59:35Z', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH:MI:SS.FFTZR')` instead of `TO_UTC_TIMESTAMP_TZ`